# DATA_READ ERROR in hive+oracle join query in apache drill

Tags: apache-drill

I tried a join query in hive & oracle:

```
select x.net_profit, y.city from hive.testdb.`catalog_sales` x inner join oracle.USER.`customer_address` y on y.address_id = x.bill_add_id
```

Data types for these fields in Drill (*I checked using `describe table`*) :

```
address_id    :  Decimal
city          :  CHARACTER VARYING

bill_addr_id  :  Double
net_profit    :  Double
```

Above query worked & I got desired output.

I tried :

```
select y.city, sum(x.net_profit) from hive.testdb.`catalog_sales` x inner join oracle.USER.`customer_address` y on y.address_id = x.bill_addr_id group by y.city
```

I got the following Exception:

> **Error: DATA_READ ERROR: The JDBC storage plugin failed while trying setup the SQL query.**
>
> sql SELECT "CA_CITY", CAST("ADDRESS_ID" AS DOUBLE) "$f13"
>   FROM "USER"."CUSTOMER_ADDRESS"
>   plugin oracle
>   Fragment 0:0
>
> [Error Id: 7a2106da-1326-4de1-81e4-338a37acd7f9 on 192.168.145.151:31010] (state=,code=0)

Since joined columns(`address_id`,`bill_addr_id`) has different datatypes ie `Decimal` & `Double` but these are similar. So,  I think this should be handled.

Is casting from `Decimal` to `Double` not possible? or is this a bug?

Comment: Did you enable the decimal type? http://drill.apache.org/docs/supported-data-types/#enabling-the-decimal-type

Comment: @catpaws yes I already did that. First thing that came in my mind was that decimal enable thing

Comment: @catpaws is this kind of **group by** query is supported in Drill for Join Queries?